# Repalce entry of $nn.idx with the custom rownames - for nn2 (RANN package in R)

Tags: r, search

I have a data.csv file which contains longitude and latitude of some locations. The content is as below

```
3.142659,101.710396
3.117592,101.67722
3.157187,101.711215
3.073167,101.607791
```

I am using RANN package to solve a Nearest Neighbour Search problem

```
library(RANN)
x <- read.csv("data.csv",sep=",", header=FALSE)
DL<-c("shop1", "shop2", "shop3", "shop4")
#To rename the rowname as per the vector i defined in the previous line of command 
row.names(x)<-DL
nearest <- nn2(x,x)
nearest
```

However, output [nearest] is as below -

```
$nn.idx
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    2    4
[2,]    2    1    3    4
[3,]    3    1    2    4
[4,]    4    2    1    3

$nn.dists
    [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,]    0 0.01455107 0.04158126 0.12392306
[2,]    0 0.04158126 0.05218644 0.08242552
[3,]    0 0.01455107 0.05218644 0.13325121
[4,]    0 0.08242552 0.12392306 0.13325121
```

I want to get the output in such a format that the entries of $nn.idx are replaced with the rownames(shop1, shop3, shop2, shop4 etc.) instead of rownumber (1, 3, 2, 4 etc.).

As for example, something like below -

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    Shop1    Shop3    Shop2    Shop4
[2,]    Shop2   Shop1    Shop3    Shop4
[3,]    Shop3    Shop1    Shop2    Shop4
[4,]    Shop4    Shop2    Shop1    Shop3
```

Looking for help.

Comment: will this `matrix(paste0("shop", data), nrow(data), ncol(data))` do what you want?

Comment: @KFB, used your code on x ...                         matrix(paste0("shop", x), nrow(x), ncol(x)) but the output is not what i am expecting ..[,1]                                                  
[1,] "shopc(3.142659, 3.117592, 3.157187, 3.073167)"       
[2,] "shopc(101.710396, 101.67722, 101.711215, 101.607791)"